# Caching ordered Spark DataFrame creates unwanted job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert a RDD to a DataFrame and want to cache the results of the RDD:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn

schema = StructType([StructField('t', DoubleType()), StructField('value', DoubleType())])

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([Row(t=float(i/10), value=float(i*i)) for i in range(1000)], 4), #.cache(),
    schema=schema,
    verifySchema=False
).orderBy("t") #.cache()
```

- If you don't use a `cache` function no job is generated.
- If you use `cache` only after the `orderBy` 1 jobs is generated for `cache`:[image]
- If you use `cache` only after the `parallelize` no job is generated.

Why does `cache` generate a job in this one case?
How can I avoid the job generation of `cache` (caching the DataFrame and no RDD)?

**Edit**: I investigated more into the problem and found that without the `orderBy("t")` no job is generated. Why?

Comment: With your updates clarifying the question, I deleted my original answer. This is an interesting question as orderBy("t") is lazily evaluated as it should be and cache() without orderBy is also lazily evaluated, but together, I too am not sure why anything is executed for purely transformer operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I submitted a [bug ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20106) and it was closed with following reason:

> Caching requires the backing RDD. That requires we also know the
>   backing partitions, and this is somewhat special for a global order:
>   it triggers a job (scan) because we need to determine the partition
>   bounds.