# Spark persist method never finishes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera

I call persist method for dataset and usually it works fine but sometimes it never finishes. I use cloudera with Spark 2.1. Does anyone experience same?

originalDataSet = originalDataSet.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());

Answer (score 1):

Just like everything else in Spark, the `persist` operation is lazily evaluated. The first time an action is taken on the underlying data, and the relevant part of the DAG is executed, then they persist will come into play.

Therefore you shouldn't and wouldn't see any problem from the `persist` command itself.

Data is persisted, in this case to memory and disk, but only to the point of capacity. If that data needs to be removed due to insufficient cache capacity then Spark will do so.

> Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out
>   old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion. If you
>   would like to manually remove an RDD instead of waiting for it to fall
>   out of the cache, use the RDD.unpersist() method.

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence

Comment: broad question => broad answer (even if it's a good one)

Comment: personally I voted to close it

Comment: thats not entirely true, cache can also launch spark jobs, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951939/caching-ordered-spark-dataframe-creates-unwanted-job and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419963/why-does-calling-cache-take-a-long-time-on-a-spark-dataset

Comment: @eliasah - good call, you're right

Comment: i misunderstood. code execution stops at this line. it has nothing to do with lazy initialization. executors are not active also and not always it rarely happens.